# modified config/ environments/ development.rb to be able to connect to an email server. When I restart rails server I get an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Doing my first rails development, modified config/ environments/ development.rb to be able to connect to an email server.  When I restart rails server I get the following error message:

> "...Ruby/learn-rails/config/environments/development.rb:39: syntax
>   error, unexpected '=', expecting => (SyntaxError)
>   ...default_url_options = { :host = > 'localhost: 3000' } ...    ".

I don't see the syntax error, anyone see where i went wrong?

The code i added to the development.rb file looks like this:

```
   config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = { 
   address: "smtp.gmail.com", 
   port: 587, 
   domain: Rails.application.secrets.domain_name, 
   authentication: "plain", 
   enable_starttls_auto: true, 
   user_name: Rails.application.secrets.email_provider_username, 
   password: Rails.application.secrets.email_provider_password 
   }
```

# ActionMailer Config

```
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host = > 'localhost: 3000'}
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp 
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is this line:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host = > 'localhost: 3000'}
```

your hashrocket has a space in it... try:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost: 3000'}
```

Also, in future, that stacktrace gives you the precise line-number that the error is on:

```
 Ruby/learn-rails/config/environments/development.rb:39
```

this says that the problem is on line 39 of `config/environments/development.rb`
You can go to precisely that line in your text editor to look for the error it's complaining about.

Comment: Thank you Taryn East, I stared at that a 1000 times and didn't see the space.

Comment: heh - that happens to the best of us :)